# Where libflutter.so come from?

Tags: flutter, flutter-engine

First I thought libflutter.so is coming from flutter engine.
But when I compile it by myself it seems not.

Since Flutter is an open source project, there might be a way to compile my own libflutter.so. Is there any way I can compile my own libflutter.so?

Comment: @underscore_d But first I should figure out where the SO come from. I'm not sure which project to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally haven't tried the Android embedder build but obviously `libflutter.so` is an output of building the engine's `//shell/platform/android:flutter_shell_native` target.

https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/flutter-2.5-candidate.8/shell/platform/android/BUILD.gn#L41

The combination of `shared_library` and `output_name = "flutter"` in GN file means that `libflutter.so` is generated as a result of build. Here's the dependency graph: `android -> flutter_jar_zip -> android_jar -> flutter_shell_native`.